# Reduce size box LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Hello everybody I am trying to reduce the space that surround the buttons of this section:
[image]

in order to make it look more visually attractive. The code is the next one:

```
       <template iterator:it={iteratorTelefono}>
          <div key={it.value.autoNumber} class="slds-grid d-flex  slds-box paddingCajas">
             <div class="lightningCardClass slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-around_small">
                <lightning-input label="Prefijo"  variant="label-hidden" data-index={it.index}  value={it.value.qx_PrefijoPais} placeholder="Prefijo" type="text" max-length="3"   onchange={handlePrefijoPais}></lightning-input>
                </div>
                     <div class="lightningCardClass slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-around_small ">
                         <lightning-input type="text"  placeholder="Número de teléfono" variant="label-hidden" data-index={it.index} value={it.value.qx_Numero} max-length="9"   onchange={handleTelefono}></lightning-input>
                     </div>
                     <div class="lightningCardClass slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-around_small" >
                        <template if:false={it.value.recordId}>
                             <lightning-button onclick={onRemoveTelefono} if:false={it.first} variant="destructive"  label='Borrar' data-index={it.index}  class="slds-var-m-left_x-small paddingFields"></lightning-button>
                        </template>
                        <lightning-button  if:true={it.value.recordId} onclick={onRemoveTelefono} variant="destructive lightningButton" label='Borrar' data-index={it.index} class="slds-var-m-left_x-small paddingFields"></lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button  onclick={onAddTelefono} if:true={it.last} data-index={it.index} class="slds-m-left_x-small paddingFields" label="Nuevo" >
             </lightning-button>
           </div>
          </div>
         </template>
```

CSS code:

```
.paddingCajas{
padding: 5px;
margin: 3px;
```

}

I applied the paddingCajas css class to test if it worked but nothing has change. Could anybody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by adjusting the class attribute `slds-p-around_small` in each direct div parents of the lightning-input / button elements.

If you need display density aware sizing `slds-var-p-around_small`, then look at the Variable Density Classes: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/#Variable-Density-Classes

| Class Name | Comfy Value | Compact Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| slds-var-p-around_xxx-small | 0.125rem | 0.125rem |
| slds-var-p-around_xx-small | 0.25rem | 0.125rem |
| slds-var-p-around_x-small | 0.5rem | 0.125rem |
| slds-var-p-around_small | 0.75rem | 0.25rem |
| slds-var-p-around_medium | 1rem | 0.5rem |
| slds-var-p-around_large | 1.5rem | 0.75rem |
| slds-var-p-around_x-large | 2rem | 1rem |
| slds-var-p-around_xx-large | 3rem | 1.5rem |